# Document viewer Keep page not working after the upgrade

Tags: server, upgrade, 22.04

I upgraded my ubuntu from 20.04 to the latest LTS version(Jammy Jellyfish)

Earlier, in the document viewer where I left it, it will open from there.

But not opening now from the same page where I left, Now the document viewer is opening from the start of the page.

How to solve this problem & what setting of the document viewer has been changed after the upgrade.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this. However, I can suggest a workaround: Use Okular. Itremembered the last position, and has many more features than the default document viewer (evince).  `sudo apt install okular`

Comment: Thanks, @ArchismanPanigrahi.
If in future you get to know why it happens in evince & know how to fix it. Please let me know.